# foreach add data into selectpicker

Tags: javascript, select

I want to be able to complete this `selectpicker` with options, but this does not add the options with that js function. I try with class  `select` and it works fine but with`selectpicker` does work.

## HTML

```
  <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-style="btn-default"
        data-placeholder=".:: Dirección ::." tabindex="-1"
       data-minimum-results-for-search="10"  id="address" name="address">
  </select>
```

## JS

```
$.each(response.result['address1'], function(k, v) {
    $('<option>').val(v.c_bpartner_location_id).text(v.address1).appendTo('#address');
 });
```

## PHP

```
$address1[] = array();
foreach($records as $row) {
    $direccion = $row - > direccion;
    array_push($address1, array("address1" => $row -> address1,
        "c_bpartner_location_id" => $row -> c_bpartner_location_id))
}
$data['result'] = array(
    'direccion' => $direccion,
    'address1' => $address1);
```

What could be the mistake?

Comment: Can you add to your question an example of response? I can't give you a good answer without knowing what data you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback for the [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function has two parameters: key and value or index in array and value.

In your case, I assume you have in `direccion` and `address1` values of scalar types. For your example, imagine we have an object like this:

```php
$data = [
  'result' => [
    'direccion' => 'left',
    'address1'  => 'Street 1, City',
  ]
];
```

So for your JS code, you should use this code:

```js
$.each(response.result['address1'], function(k, v) {
    $('<option>').val(v).text(v).appendTo('#address');
 });
```

Because for each part of the associative array `$data['result']` you will get key and value pairs (**k**, **v**):

```
k: direccion, v: left
k: address1, v: Street 1, City
```

Comment: That would work with a select class `select` but I dunno when I try with class `selectpicker` doesn't work

Comment: it work with this `$('#address').selectpicker('refresh');` thanks for you help :)

Comment: Ah, so you're using a plugin for select input. Sorry, I didn't notice this.